# C# - Using Windows Forms Applications and SQL Server; Check boxes and Groupboxes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to create a Windows Form App using C# and SQL Server 2012.

My app has two text-boxes, a button and three group-boxes each having three check-boxes. I want the app to be getting the values of check-boxes that are checked, and saving all data to one row in SQL Server.

Example:

```
ID int PK not null,
Customer_Name varchar(50)
Item_Name nvarchar(max) null
Item_Model nvarchar(max) null
Item_Color nvarchar(max) null
```

I have created 3 Group boxes to the form each having 3 check boxes:

```
GroupBox1:
  CheckBox1 - name : chkboxLaptop
  CheckBox2 - name : chkboxDesktop
  CheckBox1 - name : chkboxMonitor

GroupBox2:
  CheckBox1 - name : chkboxDell
  CheckBox2 - name : chkboxHp
  CheckBox1 - name : chkboxLenovo

GroupBox3:
  CheckBox1 - name : chkboxSilver
  CheckBox2 - name : chkboxGrey
  CheckBox1 - name : chkboxBlack
```

I want the **Demo_Table** table to look like this:

```
  ID  Customer_Name  Item_Name  Item_Model  Item_Color
  1   Mulenga        Laptop     Lenovo      Black
```

Here is my Code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Control ctrl in this.groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is CheckBox)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)ctrl).Checked == true)
                {
                    name.Append(((CheckBox)ctrl).Text.ToString() + " ");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Demo_Table (ID,Customer_Name,Item_Name) VALUES ( '" + txtBoxID.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtBoxName.Text.ToString() + "','" + ((CheckBox)ctrl).Text.ToString() + "')", con);
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data added to table");
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

The App is giving me these results:

```
  ID  Customer_Name  Item_Name  Item_Model  Item_Color
  1   Mulenga        Laptop     NULL        NULL
```

How do I add data in the **Item_Model** and **Item_Color** columns?

Your Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should NEVER, EVER use direct user input as part of an SQL query. Use parametrized queries instead, to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: You need to add the fields in the query like this: INSERT INTO Demo_Table (ID,Customer_Name,Item_Name,Item_Model,Item_Color) VALUE (...), you haven't set the Item_Model and Item_Color in the query. Also, I think you need to use Radio Buttons and not Check Boxes. Do you want to store multiple Names in the same field?

Comment: How do I set the Item_Model and Item_Color in the query? I tried using the foreach statement for the groupBox2 and groupBox3 items but was receiving an error. is there any other way I can get the values of check boxes from the groupBox2 and groupBox3 group boxes?

Comment: I only want to store selected checkbox values in the fields. Is it possible or doable using checkboxes rather than radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as xxbbcc said, **never** concatenate command text and **always** use parameters)

To achieve this, you can do something like this (comments in code)

Bear in mind that this code assumes that only one checkbox per group is selected and it will get first selected checkbox text. It would be better to use `RadioButtons` instead of `CheckBoxes`.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //find all checkbox controls in group,  get selected one  and get its text. 
    string name = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(cb => cb.Checked).Text;
    string model = groupBox2.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(cb => cb.Checked).Text;
    string color = groupBox3.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(cb => cb.Checked).Text;

    //connection
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    //command text (WITH PARAMETERS!)
    string cmdText =
        @"
            INSERT INTO Demo_Table 
                (ID,Customer_Name,Item_Name, item_model, item_color) 
            VALUES 
                (@id, @customer_name, @item_name, @item_model, @item_color)
        ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
    //add params
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBoxID.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBoxName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_model", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_color", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = color;
    //execute query
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data added to table");
}
```

if you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: No exception with `FirstOrDefault` i think.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it has finally worked. @FarzinKanzi what does the FirstOrDefault do and what would happen if I omit it from the code?

Comment: @KapambweMulenga `FirstOrDefault` returns first (or empty, default one) object from list (in this case `CheckBox` from list of checkboxes) which satisfies given condition (`Checked = true`). If you omit that, you won't get one checkbox but list of all checkboxes in that group. And, one more thing: as a way to say "thanks", mark asnwer as solution if it helped you and solved your problem.

Comment: @Nino where should I click to mark answer as solution?

Comment: @KapambweMulenga "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in" - [from help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)